# React native iOS running 1 of 1 custom shell scripts took long time

Tags: react-native-ios

When trying to debug react native app on device, it takes really long time when "running 1 of 1 custom shell scripts". It will not fail, but just take long time. Is there anybody know what process is this? And how can we shorten this time? Thank you!

Comment: I have this problem too. It used to work fine in version `0.47.2`, then I updated `react-native` to `0.48.2`. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't solve this one, but I did find out some information. For me, it seems that this is happening because the script hangs for ~15-30 seconds after it has completed the bundle (and asset copy). This is one of those cases where the main thread in a node script has completed, and node is just waiting for a promise to resolve before it quits ... and it waits too long. I was able to mitigate the problem by adding a call to `process.exit(0)` in the right place within `react/native/local-cli`, to wit:

`https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/cliEntry.js:116` (popping a .then(()=>process.exit(0) onto the end of that line.

Not an elegant solution but maybe some others can pick it up from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Mac/iOS) after updating `react-native` from `0.47.2` to `0.48.2`.
Then I came across a solution from this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15469) (I think this is what worked for me).

Anyway what I did was reinstall `watchman` as shown below:

```
brew uninstall watchman
brew install watchman
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Didnt do anything for mine sadly.